# How to sort list which having variable as list

Tags: java, collections

I have class ABC

```
class ABC{
 private List<XYZ> xyzList -- Though its list it contains single object;
 private String txt;
}
class XYZ{
 private long price;
}
```

I want to sort List abcList based on class XYZ price variable.
Please provide best possible approach for sorting in ascending order.

Answer (score 6):

Have you tried one of these methods:

```
java.util.Collections.sort(List<T>)
```

Or

```
java.util.Collections.sort(List<T>, Comparator<? super T>)
```

Answer (score 4):

One way is implement `Comparable` interface in `XYZ` and override `compareTo` and then `Collections.sort(yourListOfXYZ)` will sort the list.

Other way is using `Comparator`.

```
Collections.sort(xyzList, new Comparator<XYZ>() {
            @Override
            public int compare( XYZ e1,XYZ e2) {
                return Long.valueOf(e1.getPrice()).compareTo(Long.valueOf(e2.getPrice()));
            }
        });
```

Comment: this comes as 'why java is slow', the comparator creates 2 useless objects to compare 2 longs (each time!). If price is strictly non-negative `Long.signum(e1.getPrice()-e2.getPrice())`. Morealso sorts in **descending order**. I just don't get how it an be voted.

Comment: With Java 7, you can just do `Long.compare(e1.getPrice(), e2.getPrice())`.

Comment: @LouisWasserman, yeah there is in java7, i dunno how it's implemented for real (on assembler level). I mean if uses ternary operator it's likely to be much slower than what I proposed: `Long.signum(e1.getPrice()-e2.getPrice())` has no branches at all but works only when the signs of both parameters are the same (and no overflow). OTOH, if Long.compare is implemented/compiled w/ intrinsics it would be pretty decent and working for any long values.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

> Collections.sort(xyzList);

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you look into the documentation for the [Comparable](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Comparable.html) interface. Possible even with the use of an [PriorityQueue](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/PriorityQueue.html).

Answer (score 0):

In you case you either need to make XYZ implement `Comparable`, provide a `Comparator<XYZ>` or a simpler option is to unwrap it and just use a `List<Double>` or a `SortedSet<Double>` to hold you prices.

Answer (score 0):

Sample code from http://java2novice.com/java-collections-and-util/arraylist/sort-comparator/

```
public class MyArrayListSort {

public static void main(String a[]){

    List<Empl> list = new ArrayList<Empl>();
    list.add(new Empl("Ram",3000));
    list.add(new Empl("John",6000));
    list.add(new Empl("Crish",2000));
    list.add(new Empl("Tom",2400));
    Collections.sort(list,new MySalaryComp());
    System.out.println("Sorted list entries: ");
    for(Empl e:list){
        System.out.println(e);
    }
}
}

class MySalaryComp implements Comparator<Empl>{

@Override
public int compare(Empl e1, Empl e2) {
    if(e1.getSalary() < e2.getSalary()){
        return 1;
    } else {
        return -1;
    }
}
}

class Empl{

private String name;
private int salary;

public Empl(String n, int s){
    this.name = n;
    this.salary = s;
}

public String getName() {
    return name;
}
public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}
public int getSalary() {
    return salary;
}
public void setSalary(int salary) {
    this.salary = salary;
}
public String toString(){
    return "Name: "+this.name+"-- Salary: "+this.salary;
}
}
```